# undocumented kernel boot parameter?

Tags: linux, encryption, linux-kernel, boot, grub

It seems that the Linux kernel has a `cryptopts=...` boot parameter which allows to specify an encrypted root partition. Google search returns many examples of its use, however I was unable to locate the actual documentation. For example, `man bootparam` does not mention it. I wonder if this is an undocumented feature, or perhaps deprecated? Or maybe it is special to certain distributions?
I have even tried to `grep` the Linux kernel source for the string `cryptopts` but found nothing... Please help me to solve the mystery!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel doesn't. [The string `cryptopts` does not appear anywhere in the Linux kernel.](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/search?q=cryptopts)

However, the contents of the kernel command line are exposed to userspace in `/proc/cmdline`. Many distributions will read boot options from the command line — for instance, Debian and Ubuntu use `quiet` to suppress status messages at boot time. It's likely that `cryptopts` is used similarly.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this to me! In Debian, there is a package `cryptsetup` which contains a file `cryptroot-script` which contains these lines: `for opt in $(cat /proc/cmdline); do \n case $opt in \n cryptopts=*) ...` This resolves the "mystery"

Answer (score 2):

`cryptopts` is a boot option of [`initramfs-tools`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/initramfs-tools.8.html). This is its documentation:

> **cryptopts**
>       passes the args for  cryptoroot.  Set  by  the  cryptsetup  boot hooks.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I guess this is somewhat distribution-specific. In Debian, `cryptopts` was removed from `initramfs-tools` in 2007, with the following comment: "init: Remove cryptopts parsing, not official bootparam. cryptsetup scripts parse /proc/cmdline themselves". Indeed, the package `cryptsetup` contains a file `cryptroot-script` which parses `cryptopts`. It was briefly removed and readded in 2006.